# Sql query about pair-remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So I have to do a query where I am asked to find the count of directors who, for every pair of movies' genres, have directed both. I thought I should take two instances of genre id and two instances of directors id and find those where g_id's are different but dir_id are the same,so I tried something like this

```
select distinct g1.genre_id as genre1,
            g2.genre_id as genre2,
   count(distinct mhd1.director_id) as directors_count
from genre g1, genre g2, movie_has_genre mhg1,movie_has_genre 
     mhg2,movie_has_director mhd1,movie_has_director mhd2    
where 
(g2.genre_id <> g1.genre_id) and  (mhg1.genre_id = g1.genre_id) 
and (mhg2.genre_id = g2.genre_id) and (mhd1.movie_id = mhg1.movie_id)
and  (mhd2.movie_id = mhg2.movie_id) and (mhd1.director_id =mhd2.director_id)
group by g1.genre_id, g2.genre_id;
```

Base is

```
actor(actor_id,first_name,last_name,gender)

director(director_id,first_name,last_name)

role(movie_id,actor_id,role)

genre(genre_id,name)

movie(movie_id,title,year,rank)

movie_has_director(movie_id,director_id)

movie_has_genre(genre_id,movie_id)
```

but it is not working. What am I missing there? Thank you
**EDIT** problem seems to be I get both (a,b) and (b,a) pairs while I should get only (a,b) with a

Comment: So your question is how to find how many directors have directed at least two genres of movies?

Comment: **not working** means what? What errors / results are you getting?

Comment: Can you give some example

Comment: well,seems like I get both (a,b) and (b,a) genres,e.g I get the pair (5,40) but then I get (40,5) which,seeing the right results,was not supposed to happen. I guess this is something I can google more specifically

Answer (score 1):

First you need kind of a cross join to get all combinations of two genres: `genre g1 join genre g2 on g2.id > g1.id`. Then you need to join `movie_has_genre` and `movie_has_director` to both (`g1` and `g2`) and only keep rows where the director is the same  (`md2.director_id = md1.director_id`). The rest is basic `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`:

```
select g1.name as genre1,
       g2.name as genre2,
       count(distinct md1.director_id) as directors_count
from genre g1
join genre g2 on g2.id > g1.id
join movie_has_genre mg1 on mg1.genre_id = g1.id
join movie_has_genre mg2 on mg2.genre_id = g2.id
join movie_has_director md1 on md1.movie_id = mg1.movie_id
join movie_has_director md2 on md2.movie_id = mg2.movie_id
                           and md2.director_id = md1.director_id
group by g1.id, g2.id
```

Comment: Thank you for that,but it seems like it does the same thing with mine,I mean showing both (a,b) and (b,a) pairs

Comment: @Riseos this can be fixed very simply: Use `g2.id > g1.id` instead of `g2.id <> g1.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Paul's answer, you can get rid of duplicate (a,b), (b,a) by using `DISTINCT, LEAST, GREATEST`

```
select DISTINCT LEAST(g1.name,g2.name) as genre1, 
       GREATEST(g1.name,g2.name) as genre2,
       count(distinct md1.director_id) as directors_count
from genre g1
join genre g2 on g2.id <> g1.id
join movie_has_genre mg1 on mg1.genre_id = g1.id
join movie_has_genre mg2 on mg2.genre_id = g2.id
join movie_has_director md1 on md1.movie_id = mg1.movie_id
join movie_has_director md2 on md2.movie_id = mg2.movie_id
                           and md2.director_id = md1.director_id
group by g1.id, g2.id
```